# Cannot print out read integers: java

Tags: java, methods, io

I am creating a program that will print out digits of pi up to a number specified by the user. I can read the input from the user, I can read the text file, but when I print the number of digits, it prints out the wrong number.

"Pi.txt" contains "3.14159".
Here is my code:

```
    package pireturner;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class PiReturner {

        static File file = new File("Pi.txt");
        static int count = 0;

        public PiReturner() {

        }
        public static void readFile() {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter number of digits you wish to print: ");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                int numdigits = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

                int i;
                while((i = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    while(count != numdigits) {
                        System.out.print(i);
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
                System.err.print(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.print(e);
            }
        }            

        public static void main(String[] args ) {
            PiReturner.readFile();
        }
    }
```

This will print out "515151" if the user inputs 3 as the number of digits they wish to print. I do not know why it does this, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as there are no errors and I have tested the reading method and it works fine. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

By the way, casting integer 'i' to a char will print out 333 (assuming input is 3).

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should flag the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop is not left before outputting numdigit times 3

```
         while (count != numdigits) {
             System.out.print(i);
             count++;
         }
```

instead ...

```
    int numdigits = Integer.parseInt (scanner.nextLine ());
    // for the dot
    if (numdigits > 1) 
        ++numdigits;
    int i;

    while ((i = reader.read ()) != -1 && count != numdigits) {
         System.out.print ((char) i);
         count++;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The value 51 is the Unicode code point (and the ASCII value) for the character `'3'`.

To display `3` instead of the `51` you need to cast the `int` to `char` before printing it:

```
System.out.print((char)i);
```

You also have an error in your loops. You should have a single loop where you stop if either you reach the end of the file, or if you reach the required number of digits:

```
while(((i = reader.read()) != -1) && (count < numdigits)) {
```

Your code also counts the character `.` as a digit, but it is not a digit.

Comment: Thankyou, but that prints out "333". Would you know why that occurs?

Comment: That is great. I have gotten it to work with your loop, I will simply add "including '3.' " in the question. In future i will work out how to eliminate the '3.' (unless you already know how and care to tell). Many thanks, this has plagued me for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You only read one character from the file - '3' (character code 51, as Mark Byers points out) and then you print it 3 times.

```
     int i;
     while((count < numdigits) && ((i = reader.read()) != -1)) {
        System.out.print((char)i);
        count++;
     }
```

If the user says they want 4 digits of pi, are you intending to print `3.14` or `3.141`?

The above code would print `3.14` for 4 - because it's 4 characters.